# Segment a vector each time there is a positive value and count the number of zero within each segment to put all of them in a new vector in R

Tags: r

I've tried to find an answer for this question but couldn't. I am not sure the title is very informative but what I intend to do is, to count, in a vector, the number of 0s before a positive value, and do that each time I have 0s followed by a positive value in my vector in order to put this in a vector. In other words, I would like to cut my first vector in segments containing 0s and the first following positive, count the number of 0s in each segment, and put the number of 0s from each segment in a new vector. May be an illustration would be better :

if I have :

> x<-c(0,0,5,0,1,0,0,4)

I would like to get : 
[1] 2 1 2

So far I have been able to count the number of 0s in the code but I don't know how to specify the segmentation of the vector nor to inject it in a new vector containing all the numbers of 0s for all the segments. 
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the counts of the lengths of the runs of 0, you can use run length encoding (`rle()`) function

```
x <- c(0,0,5,0,1,0,0,4)
with(rle(x), lengths[values==0])
# [1] 2 1 2
```

You this is assuming all the non-zero values are positive and therefore break the runs.